# Sharepoint online site : Unable to open PPT files in mobile

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-integration, responsive, mobile-view, responsive-template

We are trying to open PPT files from sharepoint online (mobile enabled) site in mobile getting an error "This item might not exist or is no longer available"(but actually it exist in desktop view).

[image]